# REGEXP to extract cities/states

Tags: regex

I would like a regular expression that gets the states from the following (they are the last 2 characters in the brackets after a persons name).

```
Sinha; Rabindra K. (Ranchi, IN), Polinsky; Charles K. (Pittsburgh, PA), Cifrulak, Sr.; Stephen D. (Sewickley, PA), Wagner; Norman J. (Pittsburgh, PA).
```

So the answer for the above should be IN PA PA PA.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to solve it? What regex tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

this can work.

```
([A-Z]{2})
```

https://regex101.com/r/fZ8hB4/1

Regards.
Nelson.